# Why does $H \leq G$ and $gHg^{-1} \leq G$ have the same order?

Tags: group-theory

Say $G$ is a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and $gHg^{-1}$ a subgroup of $G$. Why do $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ have the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f:H\rightarrow gHg^{-1}$ by $$f(h)=ghg^{-1}\;\forall h\in H$$

Suppose $f(h_1)=f(h_2)$, where $h_1,h_2\in H$
Then we have $gh_1g^{-1}=gh_2g^{-1}$.
Clearly, $h_1=h_2$. So $f$ is injective.

Let $ghg^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$.
Clearly, $h\in H$ where $f(h)=ghg^{-1}$.
So $f$ is surjective.

Since $f$ is bijective, we conclude that $|H|=|gHg^{-1}|$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It's not too difficult to show that the map $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$ for any $g \in G$ is an automorphism of $G$.  Hence, its restriction to any subset of the group must *still* be injective.

Answer (score 0):

Proof follows.

> Let $h_1,h_2 \in H$, and $gh_1g^{-1} = gh_2g^{-1}$. If we multiply on the left by $g^{-1}$ and on the right by $g$ on both sides, then we see that $h_1=h_2$.
>
> Now, let $gh_3g^{-1}, gh_4g^{-1} \in H$, and $h_3=h_4$. If we multiply on the left by $g$ and on the right by $g^{-1}$, we see that $gh_3g^{-1}=gh_4g^{-1}$.
>
> This shows that conjugating by g is a one-on-one operation, i.e. for every element of $H$, there is exactly one element of $gHg^{-1}$, and vice versa. Therefore, the orders of $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ are exactly the same.